# Problem to open two forms in the same modal view

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-5

In my application I use the JavaScript\jQuery code below to load two forms in the same modal divs:

View:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
  });

  $.validator.setDefaults({
    focusInvalid: false
  });
  $('#selectLivello').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#modalFormContenitore').empty();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#modalForm").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
          $("#modalFormContenitore").html(data);

          // Enable client-side validation
          $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#selectLivelloForm");
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          // Show an error message
          $("#modalFormContenitore").html("Si è verificato un errore.</br> " + error);
          console.log(error);

          // Close the modal after 5 seconds
          setTimeout(function() {
            $("#modalForm").modal("hide");
          }, 5000);
        }
      });
    });
    $("#modalForm").modal("show");
  });

  $("#addServizio").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#modalFormContenitore').empty();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#modalForm").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
          $("#modalFormContenitore").html(data);
          // Enable client-side validation
          $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#addServizioForm");
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          // Show an error message
          $("#modalFormContenitore").html("Si è verificato un errore.</br> " + error);
          console.log(error);
          // Close the modal after 5 seconds
          setTimeout(function() {
            $("#modalForm").modal("hide");
          }, 5000);
        }
      });
    });
    $("#modalForm").modal("show");
  });
  //Gestore dell'evento submit per il form contenuto nella partial view
  $(document).on("submit", "#selectLivelloForm", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: form.attr("action"),
      type: form.attr("method"),
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function(result) {
        if (result.success) {
          // other code
          $("#modalForm").modal("hide");
        } else {
          $("#modalFormContenitore").html(result);
          $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#selectLivelloForm");
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
  });
  //Gestore dell'evento submit per il form contenuto nella partial view
  $(document).on("submit", "#addServizioForm", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: form.attr("action"),
      type: form.attr("method"),
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function(result) {
        if (result.success) {
          // other code
          $("#modalForm").modal("hide");
        } else {
          $("#modalFormContenitore").html(result);
          $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#addServizioForm");
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
  });

  $('#modalForm').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#modalFormContenitore').empty();
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="modalForm" class="modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalFormLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-keyboard="false" data-bs-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div id="modalFormContenitore">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Two links (with id addServizio and selectLivello) are use to open the modal forms.

If I repeatly open one form (for example the ddServizioForm), close it and open the other one (selectLivelloForm) the form shown is not the expected (selectlivelloForm), but the other one (addServizioForm).

It seems like some caching mechanism.

I think the problem is the same "shown.bs.modal" handler for both forms.

The simple solution is to have two different modalForm div (one for each forms).

Is it the only one ?

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version. That seems highly relevant. ASP, however, does not.

Comment: You are adding the same event handler every time you use `$("#modalForm").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {`  Perhaps cache the modal object created then put content in it and do the show/hide of that instead. ref 4.6 example https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/#varying-modal-content